# Sum even index places in Java

Tags: java

I tried to write a method (for kicks) that would sum up the digits at even places using Java recursion.
For example, the number 23495 would return 3+9 = 12.

I am unsuccessful and would appreciate hints or what I'm doing wrong.

> ```
>     int sumEven = 0;
>     int sumOdd = 0;
>     int i = 1;
> ```

```
    if (n == 0)
    return sumEven;

    if (n != 0) { 

        if (i % 2 == 0) 
        {
            i++;
            sumEven += n % 10; 
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            sumOdd += n % 10; 
        }
    } 

    return sumEven + getEven (n/=10);
```

Comment: Where you are using the recursive method ?

Comment: Post the full code, it looks like you're using class variables to track your sums and your index, but you're chopping your number to your geteven every time you recurse so "even" and "odd" change meaning every time, and you add your sum when you return but you already added it in the if so you're adding twice

Comment: True recursion would pass everything needed to do the work, to the recursive method, not use class level variables. Do not use recursion when a loop will do. A loop will nearly always do (recursion does is using the call stack as a container and a method call like a goto to achieve a looplike work anyway)

Comment: @soorapadman Last line is where the recursion occurs.

Comment: @CaiusJard This is the full code I've written up so far. This is a static method, really. It's just under public static int getEven(int n) {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to do too much - take a look at my comment on the Q

A recursive method needs an input that contains everything it needs to work with, a return value, and an execution path where it calls itself until something happens that means it doesn't need to call itself any more - without this bit it will recourse until it overflows the stack

```
int sumEveryOtherDigit(int input){

  if(input >= 100)
    return input%10 + sumEveryOtherDigit(input/100);
  else
    return input%10;

}
```

This takes the input , and if there is any point to running again (if the input is at least 100) takes the rightmost digit plus running itself again with a smaller number

Eventually the number gets so small that there isn't any point running itself again so it just returns without running itself again and that is how the recursion stops

Now from your comment on another answer it seems you want to determine even and odd as working from the left so we need to either start with the number (1630) or the number divided by ten (23495 -> 2349) - basically to start the recursion going we always want to pass in a number with an even number of digits

```
int num = 23495;
int numOfDigits = (int)Math.log10(num)+ 1;

if(numOfDigits%2==0)
 result = sumEveryOtherDigit(num);
else
  result = sumEveryOtherDigit(num/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the digits of the input number, and then sum the remainder mod 10 only for even position digits:

```
int input = 23495;
input /= 10;
int sum = 0;

while (input > 0) {
    sum += input % 10;   // add last even digit
    input /= 100;        // advance by two digits, to the next even digit
}

System.out.println("sum of even digits of input is: " + sum);
```

This prints:

```
sum of even digits of input is: 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm trying to do this recursively.

Comment: So, change the code to make it recursive; make a method that calls itself and returns the mod plus the input divided by 100, only if the input is greater than 0. Hopefully you will then see that recursion is a loop and never need to use it again. Recursion can, and should be rewritten as a loop - loops aren't limited by the max depth of the stack. To achieve recursive like processing of eg directory structures just have s container you are looping and append to it as you loop (index loop not foreach loop). Where you append determines if it's breadth first or depth first

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it as recursive but for n=1630, I expect to get 6, because 6+0 = 6. Ideas?

Comment: You seem to be determining even digits by counting from the left but this solution works from the right. Decide when you start the recursion whether you will divide the input by ten or not to align what you think of as even with what the solution considers even. If your number has an odd number of digits, divide it by ten